# Why won't this work (C++ Function Prototypes)

Tags: c++, function

Soo I got this tiny piece of code right here:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

void WhyDoesThisNotWork();



int main()
{
    void WhyDoesThisNotWork();

    return 0;
}

void WhyDoesThisNotWork()
{
    cout << "Why don't you just print this for god's sake?" << endl;
}
```

I really don't see why it won't just print on the screen what I want it too. I even copied the exact code from a book of mine but it still does not do what I want it to. Why?

Comment: Remove the `void` in `main`.

Comment: Why are declaring the function twice?  Once is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

```
int main()
{
    void WhyDoesThisNotWork();

    return 0;
}
```

Just the way you can forward declare functions in global scope, you can also do the same in function scope. And what you simply did was to re-declare the function named `WhyDoesThisNotWork` that takes no argument and returns a `void`. You can declare a function multiple times. To call it, you simply do:

```
int main()
{
    WhyDoesThisNotWork();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it :D I guess you can kinda tell I'm new :)

Answer (score 2):

Both lines `void WhyDoesThisNotWork();` are (correct) function declarations (also known as "prototypes").  You're allowed to have more than one forward declaration for the same function, and you do.

What you don't have is a call to the function.  A function call uses the function name (or a pointer to the function) and the *values* of any arguments.  The call does not name the types of the arguments or the type of the function return itself.

```
double pow(double base, double exponent);
// ^^ has   ^^             ^^   types, is a declaration

 auto pow(double base, double exponent) -> double;
// ^^      ^^           ^^                  ^^
// same declaration using funny new "trailing return type" syntax, also has types.

pow(4.0, 4.5);
// ^^ no types, is a function call
```